# Docker Swarm - Route a request to ALL containers

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Is there any sort of way to broadcast an incoming request to all containers in a swarm?

**EDIT: More info**

I have a distributed application with many docker containers. The client can send requests to the swarm and have it respond. However, in some cases, the client needs to change a state on all server instances and therefore I would either need to be able to broadcast a message or have all the Docker containers talk to each other similar to MPI, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case?

Comment: @johnharris85 I added more information, although I believe the question stands on its own without being bound to any sort of specific use case.

Comment: Auxiliary the question does standalone, but the value is not just in 'answering questions', it's in solving problems, and sometimes it's useful to know the problem that's being solved.

Comment: @johnharris85 Fair point.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to turn a unicast packet into a multicast packet, nor any common 3rd party way of doing (That I've seen or heard of).

I'm not sure what "change a state on all server instances" means. Are we talking about the running state on all containers in a single service?
 Or the actual underlying OS? All containers on all services? etc.

Without knowing more about your use case, I'd say it's likely better to design something where the request is received by one Swarm service, and then it's stored in a queue system where a backend worker would pick it up and "change the state on all server instances" for you.

Comment: I see. So basically polling using a background worker for a message? To answer your question, it's changing a runtime configuration of all server processes running on all containers in a single service. Would replacing the ingress load balancer with HAProxy and re-sending the request seem plausible?

Comment: I'm no packet expert, but I've not heard of a tool that repeats packets at the app layer of containers in Docker, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: The case that I want to use this is to drain a backend from all the haproxy containers in a swarm cluster. When I send echo "set server backend_X/serv_X state drain" | socat stdio tcp4-connect:X.X.X.X:8888 I contact a random container that is decided/load-balanced by the docker service.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your specific use case.  One way to do it is to send a `docker service update --force`, which will cause all containers to reboot.  If your containers fetch the information that is changed at startup, it would have the required effect